# How to insert data into Strong Typed DataSet?

Tags: insert, crystal-reports, dataset

I like to use strong dataset (*.xsd) for crystal reports and want to know how to insert data into Strong Dataset(*.xsd) from Normal Dataset?

Strong DataSet mean the one we create using Add new file - select Dataset from the list in a project *(let name it as DScomm.xsd )*

Now I created normal dataset as:

```vb
Dim ds As New dataset
Dim adp As New mysqldataadapter
adp.fill(ds)
```

now here: I like to insert data into DScomm from ds

> DScomm=ds  -- ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`DataTable.Merge()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.merge.aspx) or [`DataSet.Merge`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4swwh51k.aspx) methods to move the data from a weakly typed DataSet to a Strongly typed dataset if the schemas are close enough.

You can also use `DataTable.Add` to add the rows individually if you need to do some transformation.

Honestly though if at all possible you should consider populating the strongly typed dataset directly if you can.

e.g.

```vb
Dim DScomm As New MyDataSet
Dim adp As New MySqlDataAdapter
adp.fill(DSComm)
```